# how to create minio client for GCS

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, minio

I try to put some data to the s3 bucket (on storage.googleapis.com).

```
client = Minio(
    endpoint='storage.googleapis.com',
    access_key=settings.S3_ACCESS_KEY,
    secret_key=settings.S3_SECRET_KEY,
)
```

However, I get an error:

```
S3 operation failed; code: AccessDenied, message: Access denied., resource: None, request_id: None, host_id: None
```

Kindly suggest me something to try in order to get the connection.
Thanks!

I tried to look through the internet, got something about docker, but I don't use it.

If I use boto3 lib, everything is perfectly fine. I'm able to put data to the bucket.

Comment: "able to put data to the bucket" - How? That would require the same access credentials which say "denied" in your error